# building and maintaining trust

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> a. Building and maintaining trust **is** not an easy **task**.
>
> b. Building and maintaining trust **are** not an easy **task**.
>
> c. Building and maintaining trust **are** not easy **tasks**.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think in (a) 'building and maintaining trust' are seen as a single unit.

In (c) they are seen as two things.

I don't think (b) works, but I am not sure.

Comment: No, (b) doesn't work. I think most people would consider that 'building trust and then maintaining it' is one task rather then two separate ones.

Comment: (b) cannot be correct because it says, "***...are** not **an** easy **task***". Plural "are" doesn't match with the singular "task". It could be reworded, "*...are not easy **tasks***", then all three would at least be grammatically correct, if not natural English

Answer (score 1):

The sentences a) and c) are correct:

**is ... task** and **are ... tasks**

But the sentence b) has a grammatical problem: you are using the plural form of the verb *to be* for the singular form of the noun *task*:

**are ... task**, which is grammatically incorrect.